# How to draw annotations on openseadragon?

Tags: annotations, openseadragon

Is there a plugin that extends openseadragon-annotations to draw shapes like rectangle etc? Or  any help how I can extend that ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try https://github.com/picturae/openseadragonselection which does rectangles. As for how to get the best of both worlds, you should look at the code of each and see how you might combine the ideas into a new plugin (or extending one or the other).